# Cambiar de mongo a mysql - node

Tags: nodejs

Cambié mi proyecto de **node** que conectaba con **mongodb** y ahora ya conecta a **mysql**, pero tengo un inconveniente en el modelo de usuario.js ya que desde ahí llamaba a `const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');` que era parte de **mongodb** pero ahora necesito que funcione pero con **mysql** ya que **mongodb** no está y si quito `const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');` el proyecto no funciona.

usuario.js

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const UsuarioSchema = Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El nombre es obligatorio']
    },
    correo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El correo es obligatorio'],
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La contraseña es obligatoria'],
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    rol: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'USER_ROLE',
        emun: ['ADMIN_ROLE', 'USER_ROLE']
    },
    estado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    google: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },

    tipousuario: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'El tipo de usuario es obligatorio'],
},
});



UsuarioSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    const { __v, password, _id, ...usuario  } = this.toObject();
    usuario.uid = _id;
    return usuario;
}

module.exports = model( 'Usuario', UsuarioSchema );
```

Comment: desconozco tu problema.. pero algo me hace ruido... una es una base nosql y la otra es una base relacional... es tan trivial el cambio como pensas?

Comment: claramente estás hablando de 2 cosas totalmente distintas, para conectarte a una base de datos mysql, debes cambiar la librería de conexion y probablemente reescribir todos lo modelos y cambiar toda la estructura del mismo. Como dice el compañero @gbianchi, crees que con cambiar un `require` ya vas a solucionar el problema?

Comment: ya todo el cambio esta montado solo me falta modificar este archivo.

Comment: Según yo no es necesario este archivo, ya que este sirve para definir el modelo de Mongo, desde que has cambiado a MySQL (que tampoco mencionas si lo has hecho usando métodos "nativos" o con un ORM) dicho archivo pierde sentido ya que mongoose solo funciona con Mongo hasta donde tengo entendido.